# SQLAlchemy - Order a selection list by number of or_ clauses it satisfies

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

I am writing a Program in Python 3.6 which talks to a Database in SQLite.

I pass through a multiple series of **or_** clauses in my **select(  ).where(or_)** .
Is there any way of ordering the list (that is a result of my selection) by the number of or_ clauses which it satisfies??

This is an example:

```
result5 = conn.execute(select([mytable]).where(or_( mytable.c.filename == myfile , mytable.c.id ==  3 , mytable.c.date == mydate )))
```

I would like the program to select any item in my database which has either of the three parameters. But I would like it to order all the items by the number or or clauses they satify. So if a file has all three parameters then it comes up at the top of my list.

I have no knowledge of anything other than SQL Expression Language of SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the results of the boolean expressions as integers and add them up:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

preds = [mytable.c.filename == myfile,
         mytable.c.id == 3,
         mytable.c.date == mydate]
stmt = select([mytable]).\
    where(or_(*preds)).\
    order_by(reduce(operator.add, [p.cast(Integer) for p in preds]).desc())

result5 = conn.execute(stmt)
```

In SQLite the cast might even be unnecessary, since SQLite does not have an actual boolean type, but one might argue that it is better not to rely on implicit coercions and the code is more portable this way. Note that if 2 or more rows match the same amount of predicates, their order is indeterminate.